# JPA EntityManger Transction Commit with error

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a table A_TABLE, through entityManger going to commit record using begin transction and try to commit. but in table we have combination of some value is there then throwing  ORA-00001: unique constraint exception. And that transction is not active can't able to rollback.

So I deleted that record in DB, try to save same value record with new entityManger transction begin, but its try to saving the record two times, because old one got ORA-00001: unique constraint exception entity also going in this transction to DB and in console two insert is calling.

Need solution for this,

**Code :**

@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManger;

```
TableEntity entityObject = new TableEntity(); // Always creating new objects

entityObject .setYear(2018); // Combination of year and month 

//if its availbe in DB its throw ORA-00001: unique constraint exception

entityObject .setMonth(01);
if (!entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
}

entityManager.persist(entityObject);

try{
            if (entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                entityManager.getTransaction().rollback(); // Not come to this part when ORA-00001: unique constraint exception occur
            }
            throw e;
        }
```

INSERT call twice above code after delete unique record from DB, but still throwing ORA-00001: unique constraint exception occur because old one got ORA-00001: unique constraint exception entity also going in this transction to DB and in console two insert is calling.

Comment: Please share the entire code(entity code as well)

Comment: Added TableEntity

Comment: Please show your mapping and also tell use how the unique constraint is defined that is violated

Comment: Mapping happens in DB side, when we insert if Year - 2018 and month -01 is already avaiable in DB its throw ORA-00001: unique constraint.

Comment: `because old one got ORA-00001` , this does not make any sense and mostly smells like a functional flow issue rather than hibernate or db side error. If you could post the Entity structure plus your full flow. Also does not make any sense to try inserting an entity although you already know that there might be the same inside and simply catch it as an error.....

Comment: I found the issue cause and got solution